# PhpMyAdmin displays characters incorrectly

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin does not display characters correctly (or as the way I want them to be displayed) when I try to browse tables or make queries. However, everything displays correctly if 'SET NAMES LATIN1;' is included before a query. Also, everything displays correctly on server side when using command line client. I have tried to change MySQL connection collation setting to latin1 on phpMyAdmin front page but it has no effect. I don't understand why this is happening. Is this caused by communication problem or double encoding or what?

MySql server settings (from command line client):

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by "not correctly"?

Comment: for example: lisÃ¤tiedot (should be lisätiedot)

Comment: Check also what encoding your browser uses when it displays that page. It could be possible that the server sends an incorrect charset heading, the page has incorrect set in a `meta` element or that the search results are outputted using different encoding than the rest of the page which causes browser's encoding detection to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` above your query.

Or, if you're using mysqli:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die('Error connecting to the database');

if (!mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($dbc));
}
```

Comment: And I would suggest setting `default-character-set=utf8` in your `/etc/my.cnf`. To change your current db: `ALTER DATABASE your_db_name charset=utf8;`

Comment: I'm trying to export the data using phpMyAdmin so I can't insert any php commands there. Also, It is not possible to edit my.cnf because I'm using third party hosting service. I tried to export the data using cpanel mysql dump, but the text in export file is garbled. Does this mean that the data in database is garbled?

Comment: I managed to export the data correctly using mysqldump command with charset parameter: `mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1`. And after coverting the database to utf-8, everything displays correctly. However, I still don't understand why phpMyAdmin is not working properly with latin1 database.

Comment: Are you able to execute SQL commands? You could try `ALTER DATABASE your_db_name charset=utf8;` and see if it still gives the same crap.. The phpMyAdmin is using the default characterset as defined in its php.ini settings, which is currently not similar to your db :-)